# How to identify field value has changed in ASP.Net - C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page in asp .net , requirement is very common, when the form is open for editing if a user changes value of any of the field on the page and click on cancel , then the code must ask user that "There are some changed value do you want to continue.". On yes saving will be discarded . 
Also if user do not make changes form will not show the alert message. I need it c# , if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like something that should happen on the client side - no need for ASP.NET intervention here.

What i would do is wire up change events for the input fields. When a field has changed, set a global variable.

Then on **Cancel** button *onclick* event, call a JavaScript function, if the variable is set, show the message box.

Answer (score -1):

It should be done on client side using JS. I'm using the following method:

1. Add some custom attribute to text box, e.g. originalvalue="myvalue" (this value should be same as value that used to fill a text box, it is not a good practice but it works)
2. Check all text boxes and compare current value and "originalvalue" attribute.
3. If these values are different then show alert message.

Something like this (using jQuery):

```
$("#mydiv input[type=text]).each(function() {
    if($(this).val() != $(this).attr("originalval")) {
        alert('modified');
    }
});
```

There is no need to check it on server side.

Hope this helps...